# CRM queue search result jumps back to the queue "Queues I'm a member of"

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I am having a very strange problem in CRM 2016 SP1 on-premise. When I go the Work module page, the queue defaults to "Queues I'm a member of". Then when I select another queue from the drop down list and search for some data in the list by typing it in the Quick Find field ("search for records" field) and press the search button, the queue is set back to the above mentioned default queue.

How can I get the search result to stay on the queue I selected?

I have system admin rights and a member of the root business unit and I am able to see work items in all other queues.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you a member of the queue you are trying to query?

Comment: Hi Jacob. I am not. However I can see all work items in all queues when I go to the Work module page and select different queues. But when I try searching for the items I can see in those queues, the result defers back to the "Queues I'm a member of" and comes back empty.

Comment: So are you able to see data for the queues you are a member of or no? If so, it seems like this is functioning correctly unless I am not understanding your issue.

Comment: Hello again Jacob. And many thanks for bothering to answer my question and following it. Nobody else has answered it yet. As I said I can see work items in all queues including the ones I am a member of. This could be due to the fact that I am a member of the root business unit though I cannot be sure as I am still a newbie to CRM. However, I still don't understand why this is expected behaviour and why I cannot search for work items in other queues. I very much appreciate a good explanation as I'm yet to find a proper article on this on the internet.